# xamarin.forms How to refresh a contentview and contentpage?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have `ContentView` in `CarouselPage`. I navigate to `ConentPage` from `ContentView`. Update `ContentPage` and return back to `ContentView`.

Now, on this note, my `ContentView` not get updated.

Also If I change text in entry in `ContentView`and go to `ContentPage`and return back, my change in entry is erased.

So, Is there any mechanism so that when I get back to `ContentView` it get refresh ?

I tried using `OnAppearing()`method in `ContentView` but it shows error like `ContentView does not contain definition for OnAppearing()`.

Thank you. :)

Comment: firstly, stop using `CarouselPage` - move to `CarouselView`. all your problems _might_ go away, and even if they don't, it's still highly unadvised to use `CarouselPage`.

Comment: @Nika Thanks for commenting. I tried using CarouselView but problem is still there. Contentview does not get refreshed when I move from ContentPage.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by nagivating from ContentPage to ContentView and back? Normally you only can Navigate bewteen Pages

Comment: use MessagingCenter (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/)

Answer (score 0):

Run your code inside

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
   ///Code to update view here
});
```